# Creating a payment with a single click

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is it possible to send money to a other PayPal account or credit card by using the PayPals API with a single click on a button?

Stripe is offering a solution for this, however not much countries are supported, for example India. Link to stripe here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#creating-payments

How can i achieve this with PayPal, or if there is a better solution i would like to know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stripe-connect instead of simple stripe. For more details read the stripe connect documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect

Stripe support large number of currencies, please read this FAQ here: https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-currencies-does-stripe-support

Comment: Currency support is something different then global support.
See: https://stripe.com/global to see what countries support connect